# How to remove app icon programmatically from jail broken iPhone app?

Tags: ios, ios5, jailbreak

How to remove my application icon for my app functionality? I want to do it only in jail break devices.

Comment: you can accept an answer to your questions by clicking the checkmark next to them.

Comment: You mean that flag icon....

Comment: @ChandraPrakahs no, that's for flagging (what a surprise). When I write checkmark, I mean checkmark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to modify the Info.plist file in your app bundle to include this:

```
<key>SBAppTags</key>
<array>
    <string>hidden</string>
</array>
```

([source](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/hide-applications.76176/))

Comment: Thanks man. Tell me one thing more. It will be applicable only for Jail Break devices or for all devices.

Comment: @ChandraPrakash it works on all devices, but it won't be accepted in the AppStore.

Comment: iOS8 beta 5: <SBAppTags> field from the application plist is only being read if it's a system application - anyone has a different solution?

Comment: @RomanBlachman>>System application means, default/apple apps? I'm also looking for the iOS8 solution. kindly share, if you have got any solutions.

Comment: @RomanBlachman By System application, do you mean the default Apple apps installed on the device??