# How does one programmatically start a hidden app on iOS / iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iphone-privateapi, lte

How can I run a "hidden" app on a non-jailbroken device?

FieldTest app is a hidden app on ios devices, and can be started by typing a series of keys on the iPhone phone app keypad.  I would like to run FieldTest on iPad, but iPad doesn't have a phone app/keypad.  In older versions of IOS one is able to run it by doing the 5-finger swipe while in Safari, but it no longer works.

How to run FieldTest app on an iPad (even, and especially programmatically)?

Comment: What's a "hidden" app, exactly?

Comment: I think he's referring to http://www.cultofmac.com/128306/access-the-hidden-field-test-app-for-iphone-ios-tips/

Comment: @AlexWayne, a hidden app is one whose icon does not show on the SpringBoard.  [This is how you can accomplish this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13789177/119114)

Comment: That's correct Matt; I want to run that FieldTest app.

Comment: Nate, that link shows how to hide/unhide one's own app by editing the app's info.plist.  However, I don't own FieldTest app.  iOS devices come with FieldTest app (and other hidden apps) already installed.  Anyway, without jailbraking the ipad, I'm not sure how to even access FieldTest app's info.plist.  That's why I'm looking for a way of somehow calling that app (starting its execution) from my own app - if such a thing is possible.

Comment: What about using `UIApplication openURL` with a `tel:` URL and that special number?

Comment: @RaminAhangarzadeh, yes, I realize this.  I was responding to Alex Wayne's question (That's why I used `"@"` and then his username to start my comment).  If I had an answer to your question, I would have posted it below.  That said, the technique I linked to **is** how FieldTest.app hides its icon.  But, I don't know how to start the app if your device is not jailbroken, as I think an entitlement is required to do that.

Comment: @Nate, thanks for the clarification.  I've been drilling down into source of the link you provided and it has helped me learn a lot.  Thanks again!

Comment: @maddy, I tried typing this into Safari...  tel://*3001#12345#*   but I got an error saying this:  Safari cannot open this page because it is a local file.   Then I tried this, but it returned NO.       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://*3001#12345#*"]]           I'll keep playing with it....

Comment: BTW, I tried the above using my own home land line phone from my app and ran it on my iphone and my app successfully called my land line.  I also typed it into safari and it also successfully called my land line.  But unfortunately the magic key sequence, which works fine when typed into the keypad, does not work when using tel:// neither via safari nor programatically.

Comment: No problem.  I think what you need is to be able to launch `/Applications/FieldTest.app/FieldTest`, or the bundle id `com.apple.fieldtest`.  The problem is that I don't know how to launch an app without having access to jailbreak functionality, or a custom URL scheme (which FieldTest doesn't seem to support).  Things like `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()` require your app being installed outside the normal sandbox, or having the `com.apple.springboard.launchapplications` entitlement, which I don't know how to get without jailbreaking.

Comment: I am not sure whether it's possible or not (never tried it), but it makes sense to try dowload Phone app from iPhone and install it on iPad. If you will be succesfull then you may try to type that combination.

Comment: @VictorRonin, thanks; I thought about that, but I'm not sure where to even start ... without jailbreaking.

Comment: 2Ramin: Try to ask this as separate question. I think somebody should have done it. My guess would be - you install some file browser using which you copy files, zip them and rename to .ipa and install through iTunes

Answer (score 0):

It may possible to install an app without icon on non-jailbroken ios device but you cant run it in background. And this application cannot be distributed through Appstore.