# SBAppTags key to hide the iOS app from the home screen is not working in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

The SBAppTags below mentioned is used to hide the iOS application from the home screen.

```
     <key>SBAppTags</key>
     <array>
     <string>hidden</string>
     </array>
```

It works fine up to iOS 7.x. But in iOS 8 the app is not getting hide.

Is there any way to achieve this in iOS 8?

Kindly share your knowledge / ideas.

Comment: Facing the same issue but clueless!

Comment: One guy said that the SBAppTags key is readable only be the system apps. But still searching for the solutions. If you find anything pls let me know it's urgent. Thanks for the reply dude.

Comment: @satheeshwaran have a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788611/how-to-remove-app-icon-programatically-from-jail-broken-iphone-app